# How to solve an ODE with concepts of linear stability and range of constants $y''+\sin(y)=K$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A function $y(x)$ is required to satisfy the ODE:

$y''+\sin(y)=K$

where $K$ is a constant.

Now how can we find the equilibrium points, if any, of $y$ and the range of $K$?

Also how can we determine and discuss the linear stability of the equilibrium points? When I was asked this question, I could not understand linear stability and range of constants. The very first thing that comes to my mind is the dependence on range of $\sin(y)$,

$$-1\le \sin(y)\le1$$

However, I still cannot relate it to the concepts of linear stability, equilibria and range. Could you shortly define and possibly give any hints to solve the problem?

P.S. I already looked up to the books by E.Kreyszig or Boyce but could not find a clue...

Comment: Did you try writing the ODE as a system i.e $$y' = z, \quad z' = K - \sin y$$ and then determine the equilibria, linearise etc? We can also find a conserved quantity by multiplying the ODE by $y'$ and integrating to get $$\frac{1}{2} y'^{2} - \cos y - Ky = C$$

Comment: thank you for your comment. The problem is that I cannot determine the equilibria, linearise and range of K with such a constant. Could you give a bare example how to do that with possibly a more simpler problem?

Comment: Maybe see equation (4.9), example (4.8), page 25 in Olvers lecture notes [here](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~olver/ln_/odq.pdf).

Comment: @mattos I tried to solve according to ex4.8 in the file you attached but I could not still solve the question completely. After converting it to ODE to find equilibria, $K=siny$ then equilibria points are $y=arcsinK$, so the range of K can be infinite? Also do not know how to linearise it...